# Resharper: How to suppress inspection errors resulting from CSS hacks?

Tags: css, resharper

The code in question is this:

```
/*fix ie transform offset*/
.adAffiliate.adDeclarationPosition-Right .adAffiliate-header
{
   *left: -20px    !important; /* IE 7 (IE6 also uses this, so put it first) */
   _left: -20px    !important; /* IE 6 */
    left: -20px\0/ !important; /* IE 8-9 */
}
```

[image]

As you can see, the first two lines get recognized as CSS hacks. They do not appear in the solution error list. I just want to get rid of the 3rd line appearing in the solution error list. **Unfortunately, "ignore error" does not work across VS restarts.** Is there a way to suppress this particular error? Maybe a special "ignore comment"?

This is the only CSS hack I have in 1000s of LOC. I just did not find a way out this time. And I am ok with this hack being there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just change severity for this type of error by pressing **Alt+Enter** at the error highlighting, selecting **Inspection options...** and setting severity to **Warning** or lower.

This would force the issue to disappear from the **Errors in Solution** tool window which, obviously, shows only error-level issues. Mind you, inspection severity changes persist across VS restarts.

Of course, this solution implies that whenever your code happens to have a similar issue somewhere else, you won't be able to observe it through **Errors in Solution**: you'll either have to keep your eye on ReSharper issue highlighting in the code editor (a useful habit anyway) or inspect your code with **ReSharper > Inspect > Code Issues in *scope***

Comment: Yeah I usually want this error to be reported. But I think I will actually choose this hack. Jetbrains declined my request to support this particular hack (although they do support others. I think I did not get through to the right person).

Comment: Can you point me to the request that was declined? Actually I think a more general solution would be to introduce "ReSharper ignore comments" in CSS similar to those provided for C# and VB.NET.

Comment: On another note, where did you get those hilarious gutter icons from? :)

Comment: Those icons with skull and bones on your screenshot

Comment: I thought they came from Resharper. But if it is not that they must come from the WebEssentials extension.

Comment: Right, this is from [WebEssentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f) - apparently this icon accompanies actions targeted at IE :) Anyway, I've looked at the request. Quite a bit of arrogance there from the developer, sorry about that. I've submitted a [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-287652) to allow ignore comments to account for any kind of CSS hacks there are. Please vote and watch if you like, and let's hope it gets some attention from the team.

Answer (score 2):

You call it CSS hacks, I call it invalid CSS (and the validator does it too). I recommend to use different css files included by i.e. [conditional comments](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_Comments). This is more work, but it is much cleaner.

Comment: This is the only CSS hack I have in 1000s of LOC. I just did not find a way out this time. And I am ok with this hack being there.

Comment: There is very little reason to validate your CSS. Hacks are actually easier to maintain because all of the styles are in the same location.